# Ascii to hex conversion

Tags: assembly

I am working on a code for addition of n hexadecimal numbers.
This is the part of code I am not getting

```
packnum:

xor bl,bl

mov ecx,02      ; For two digit numbers

mov esi,numascii


up1:

rol bl,04           ; Multiply by 10

mov al,[esi]

cmp al,39h

jbe skip

sub al,07h


skip:
sub al,30h

add bl,al

inc esi

loop up1

ret
```

Why compare al with 39h?
And if not equal why subtract 07h from al? Is this ascii to hex conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

39 hex is 57 decimal, which is the ASCII value for the digit 9.

The ASCII values from 30 hex to 46 hex are:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F
30                39              41        46 (hex)
```

The digits 0 to 9 are ASCII 30 hex to 39 hex, and A to F are ASCII 41 hex to 46 hex.

There are 7 characters in between the 9 and the A, which you need to account for. So, to convert from ASCII to hex, if the ASCII value is greater than 39 hex, subtract 7, so that A to F now correspond to hex values of 3a hex to 3f hex:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
30                            3f (hex)
```

Then you can just subtract 30 hex and your ASCII values will be converted to the hexadecimal values 0-F. Obviously, this algorithm is only working for uppercase representation.

As mentioned by dwelch in a comment, you can handle both upper and lowercase by ANDing with 0xf instead of subtracting 0x30, because uppercase letters will be in the range 0x3a to 0x3f and lowercase letters will be in the range of 0x5a to 0x5f.

Comment: _"39 hex is 59 decimal"_. 57.

Comment: @Michael oops, yes it is

Comment: to handle lower case the last step is an and with 0xF instead of subtract 0x30.  at that point numbers are 0x30 to 0x39, upper case are 0x3A to 0x3F  lower case would be 0x5A to 0x5F.  anding with 0xF leaves 0x0 to 0xF for all of those.

Comment: @dwelch Thanks for help